# make shortcut for livewallpaper select activity

Tags: android

I will make livewallpaer.
For new android user, I want to offer shortcut for livewallpaper selection.
In api, only image can set wallpaper.
I cannot find livewallpaper set api.
So, in activity, I want to do this thing.
1. set livewallpaper directly. or
2. show livewallpaper select activity(my device call com.android.wallpaper.livepicker/.LiveWallpaperListActivity )

.LiveWallpaperListActivity cannot call outside.
android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER show chooser.

just show picture for how to set livewallpaper?

do you have some idea?

Answer (score 0):

oops...

**WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER**

can start livewallpaper setting.

I only search in Intent or log.